# Godaddy CNAME or HTACCESS for AWS S3

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-s3, apache2, cname

I am trying to point

s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com to mystuff.mydomain.com

Tried creating a CNAME but that didn't work.  Any other options?  Can I some how use .htaccess rewrite.  I need to mask the source of files so that users with naked eye cannot see which amazon bucket I am hitting.

Comment: *"Tried creating a CNAME but that didn't work."*  Well, try it again... because that **does** work, as long as the bucket name is the same as the hostname you're pointing to it.  If it doesn't work, you need to be more specific about how it behaves compared to what you expect.  S3 has no support for `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is:

- Create an **Amazon S3 bucket** with the name of your desired domain, eg `mystuff.mydomain.com`
- Turn on **Static Website Hosting**. You will receive a URL similar to: `mystuff.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com`
- Create a **CNAME record** for your domain, pointing to the above URL

See: [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)